# How can i close video window with timer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, timer

I am using Mask detect code from github(I changed little) and trying to close video window with timer(or function like timer).  This code detect mask and show text "Mask", or "No Mask". I want to close window when label showed "Mask" for 5seconds.
I tried using timer code

```
def startTimer():
    global count
    timer = threading.Timer(1, startTimer)
    timer.start()
    print(count)
    count += 1
    if count > 5:
        timer.cancel()
```

but it doesn't work well. There are 3 problems with it.

1. Timer ran but it does not work in seconds.

2.And timer should stop when count become 5, but it goes up to 9 then window close.
3. When label showed "Mask", video stop.
I want to know how to close window with timer in this code, and how to fix these 3 problems.
I would be really appreciate for your help

```
from imutils import video
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
import threading
from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops import truediv
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
    # grab the dimensions of the frame and then construct a blob
    # from it
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (300, 300),
        (104.0, 180.0, 124.0))

    # pass the blob through the network and obtain the face detections
    faceNet.setInput(blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()

    # initialize our list of faces, their corresponding locations,
    # and the list of predictions from our face mask network
    faces = []
    locs = []
    preds = []

    # loop over the detections
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
        # the detection
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        # filter out weak detections by ensuring the confidence is
        # greater than the minimum confidence
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
            # the object
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            # ensure the bounding boxes fall within the dimensions of
            # the frame
            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

            # extract the face ROI, convert it from BGR to RGB channel
            # ordering, resize it to 224x224, and preprocess it
            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)

            # add the face and bounding boxes to their respective
            # lists
            faces.append(face)
            locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

    # only make a predictions if at least one face was detected
    if len(faces) > 0:
        # for faster inference we'll make batch predictions on *all*
        # faces at the same time rather than one-by-one predictions
        # in the above `for` loop
        faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
        preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)

    # return a 2-tuple of the face locations and their corresponding
    # locations
    return (locs, preds)

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-f", "--face", type=str,
    default="face_detector",
    help="path to face detector model directory")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str,
    default="mask_detector.model",
    help="path to trained face mask detector model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load our serialized face detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face detector model...")
prototxtPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"], "deploy.prototxt"])
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"],
    "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

# load the face mask detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face mask detector model...")
maskNet = load_model(args["model"])

# initialize the video stream and allow the camera sensor to warm up
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640)
vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)
time.sleep(1.0)
count = 0
Maskon = False
def startTimer():
    global count
    timer = threading.Timer(1, startTimer)
    timer.start()
    print(count)
    count += 1
    if count > 5:
        timer.cancel()

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to have a maximum width of 400 pixels

    check, frame = vs.read()
    if isinstance(frame, np.ndarray):
            pass
    else:
            continue
    

    # detect faces in the frame and determine if they are wearing a
    # face mask or not
    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)

    # loop over the detected face locations and their corresponding
    # locations
    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        # unpack the bounding box and predictions
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred

        # determine the class label and color we'll use to draw
        # the bounding box and text
        label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)
        if label == "Mask":
            Maskon = True
        else:
            Maskon = False
        # include the probability in the label
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)


        # display the label and bounding box rectangle on the output
        # frame
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)
        if Maskon == True:
            startTimer()
            


    
    # show the output frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if count == 5:
        break

        
    

# do a bit of cleanup
vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it!
Not working in seconds, but it works how i wanted.

```
from imutils import video
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
import threading
from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops import truediv
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
    # grab the dimensions of the frame and then construct a blob
    # from it
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (300, 300),
        (104.0, 180.0, 124.0))

    # pass the blob through the network and obtain the face detections
    faceNet.setInput(blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()

    # initialize our list of faces, their corresponding locations,
    # and the list of predictions from our face mask network
    faces = []
    locs = []
    preds = []

    # loop over the detections
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
        # the detection
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        # filter out weak detections by ensuring the confidence is
        # greater than the minimum confidence
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
            # the object
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            # ensure the bounding boxes fall within the dimensions of
            # the frame
            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

            # extract the face ROI, convert it from BGR to RGB channel
            # ordering, resize it to 224x224, and preprocess it
            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)

            # add the face and bounding boxes to their respective
            # lists
            faces.append(face)
            locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

    # only make a predictions if at least one face was detected
    if len(faces) > 0:
        # for faster inference we'll make batch predictions on *all*
        # faces at the same time rather than one-by-one predictions
        # in the above `for` loop
        faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
        preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)

    # return a 2-tuple of the face locations and their corresponding
    # locations
    return (locs, preds)

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-f", "--face", type=str,
    default="face_detector",
    help="path to face detector model directory")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str,
    default="mask_detector.model",
    help="path to trained face mask detector model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load our serialized face detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face detector model...")
prototxtPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"], "deploy.prototxt"])
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"],
    "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

# load the face mask detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face mask detector model...")
maskNet = load_model(args["model"])

# initialize the video stream and allow the camera sensor to warm up
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640)
vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)
time.sleep(1.0)
count = 0
Maskon = False
def startTimer():
    global count
    timer = threading.Timer(1, startTimer)
    timer.start()
    print(count)
    count += 1
    if count > 5:
        timer.cancel()

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to have a maximum width of 400 pixels

    check, frame = vs.read()
    if isinstance(frame, np.ndarray):
            pass
    else:
            continue
    

    # detect faces in the frame and determine if they are wearing a
    # face mask or not
    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)

    # loop over the detected face locations and their corresponding
    # locations
    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        # unpack the bounding box and predictions
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred

        # determine the class label and color we'll use to draw
        # the bounding box and text
        label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)
        if label == "Mask":
            Maskon = True
        else:
            Maskon = False
        # include the probability in the label
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)


        # display the label and bounding box rectangle on the output
        # frame
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)
    
            

    
    
    # show the output frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if Maskon == True:
        startTimer()
    else:
        count = 0
    if count > 70:
        break

        
    

# do a bit of cleanup
vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code does not work in seconds, and i am still trying to make it work in seconds.
I'd really appreciate for your help